# ODataModel error: Invalid metadata document (Initial loading of metadata failed)

Tags: odata, sapui5, database-metadata, hana-xs, xsodata

I'm trying to read an OData but I'm getting this error and I don't understand why:

[image: OData error messages]

The function which I invoke is the below:

```js
_getHanaData: function() {
  var xsODataModel = new sap.ui.model.odata.v2.ODataModel("/catalog/");
  // ...
},
```

As shown in the image below, metadata are retrieved and the status of request is 200:

[image: OData service document metadata response]

Comment: Your service is an OData V4 service, try `sap.ui.model.odata.v4.ODataModel`.

Comment: Also it is more reliable to declare your models in `manifest.json` and access them via `getModel` method of the view.

Comment: The OData specification has versions which are not compatible with each other. In your app, you're telling UI5 to fetch V2-compliant OData service document. But what your OData service actually delivers is V4-compliant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggest in the comments, the problem is the OData version. I've fixed the issue using `sap.ui.model.odata.v4.ODataModel`. In the fourth version of OData, the right way to perform *CRUD* requests is by using [bindings](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/topic/54e0ddf695af4a6c978472cecb01c64d). I've found this [official tutorial](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/topic/bcdbde6911bd4fc68fd435cf8e306ed0) very useful in order to understand how they work.